# Why chaining on String.trim() throws Exception?

Tags: java, string

Sorry if it's a stupid question, but I can't find an explanation.

I have a String like this :

```
String str ="This is 50 test. Try it !!";
```

I want to get the number just before `test`.

If I do :

```
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("test")).trim();
str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(" ")).trim();
System.out.println(str);
```

I get : `"50"`

However if I do this :

```
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("test")).trim().substring(str.lastIndexOf(" ")).trim();
```

I get : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -13`

Since `trim()` returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted, why this exception is thrown ? Why can't I chain my methods call on `str` ? I can't understand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("test")).trim().substring(str.lastIndexOf(" ")).trim();
                                                             ^
```

This `str` refers to the *original* string.

---

```
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("test")).trim();  // first operation
str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(" ")).trim();
                    ^
```

This `str` refers to the string after the first operation is applied. Therefore, the two approaches are not equivalent.